# add relevant information tooltip echarts4r boxplot outliers

Tags: javascript, r, tooltip, echarts, echarts4r

I am trying to add some relevant hover information to the tooltip of a echarts4r plot. I want to make an boxplot that shows the user the name (or some other information) of the outliers.
This is somewhat related to [Add extra variables to tooltip pie chart echarts4r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104989/add-extra-variables-to-tooltip-pie-chart-echarts4r) and [Add extra variables to tooltip pie chart echarts4r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104989/add-extra-variables-to-tooltip-pie-chart-echarts4r), but those solutions do not work as `bind` does not work for `e_boxplot`.

This is what I have so far

```r
library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame(
    my_name = letters[1:11],
    x = c(1:10, 25),
    y = c(1:10, -6)
)

df |>
    e_charts() |>
    e_boxplot(y, outliers = TRUE) |>
    e_boxplot(x, outliers = TRUE) |>
    e_tooltip(
      formatter = htmlwidgets::JS("
        function(params)
        {
          return `<strong>${params.name}</strong>
            <br/>val: ${params.value[1]}
          <br/>name: ${params.my_name}`
        }
      "))
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I was able to get this to work was to do it manually. I've added a debugger statement to the formatter. You can print the echart and use the View in browser button:
[image: View in browser]

Open up the Chrome Devtools console and roll over your scatter dot and the debugger will open in your callback function for you to explore the `value` object and get the desired information out of it for forming your tooltip.
The object `val` will already have you y-axis value if you just want to work with that.

Hope this helps!

```
e <- df |>
        e_charts() |>
        e_boxplot(y, outliers = TRUE) |>
        e_boxplot(x, outliers = TRUE) |>
        e_tooltip(
          trigger = "item"
        )
      # Series 2 is the outlier scatter layer
      e$x$opts$series[[2]]$tooltip <- list(
        formatter = "(value) => {
           var val = value.value[1];
          debugger;
           // your subsequent changes
        }")
```